# DFT sinusoid's fundamental frequency, intuitively

Tags: dft, window-functions, fundamental-frequency

I am trying to understand, intuitively, the mapping of a sinusoidal signal's fundamental frequency from time domain to frequency domain using $\textrm{DFT}$ formula. Given the time domain samples $\{x[0], x[1], \dots, x[N - 1]\}$; we have from the $\textrm{DFT}$ formula:

$X(f_k) = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1}x[n]\exp\left(-j2\pi f_kn\right)\tag{1} \label{dft}$

for $f_k = k/N$ and $k =0, 1, \cdots, N - 1$.

For this purpose I used a sinusoidal signal in Matlab and its windowed version. Here is an excerpt from my Matlab code:

```
Fs = 1000; 
Ts = 1/Fs;
t = 0:Ts:(1000 - 1)*Ts; %1sec

A = 2;
F = 20; 
y1 = A*sin(2*pi*F*t); 
y2 = y1.*hann(length(y1))';

nfft = 2^nextpow2(length(y1));
Fy = (Fs/2)*linspace(0, 1, nfft/2+1);

Y1 = 2*abs(fft(y1, nfft));
Y1(1) = .5*Y1(1);
Y1 = Y1./max(Y1);

Y2 = 2*abs(fft(y2, nfft));
Y2(1) = .5*Y2(1);
Y2 = Y2./max(Y2);
```

See the figure below for the time domain and frequency domain plots of the signals

[image]

I have two questions:

1. How can one intuitively see that the linear combination of exponentials from $\eqref{dft}$ will yield a sum with an absolute amplitude $\left| X(f_k)\right|$ that has a maximum at the fundamental frequency $\textrm{F = 20 Hz}$ ? Or is this an optimization problem of the absolute amplitude spectrum $\left|X(f_k)\right|$ wrt to $f_k$ ? Or is this just the magic of the $\textrm{DFT}$ ?
2. How is the tapering of the signal by non-rectangular window explain from $\eqref{dft}$ the *better* localization of the maximum at $\textrm{F = 20 Hz}$ (i.e minimized leakage around the fundamental frequency) ? I am well aware of the theory on windows, leakages. I'm more looking for an explanation based on equation $\eqref{dft}$. From the visual inspection of $y_1$ and $y_2$ on the top figure, how could one conclude, from the linear combinations in $\eqref{dft}$, the difference of shapes in  $\left|Y_1(f_k)\right|$ and $\left|Y_2(f_k)\right|$?

Comment: i noticed that you have exactly 20 cycles of the sinusoid in the plotted window.  is that your entire DFT length?  it appears to be so and that your DFT would be operating on a length 1000 block of data.  then, for the rectangular window (which is really no window at all), the spike at 20 Hz should be 1 FFT bin thick.  there should be no little blue "skirts" on the side as shown.  not if there are exactly an integer number of cycles in the FFT input buffer.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yes. I have a 20 Hz signal for a second of duration, hence the 20 cycles. It is the entire length DFT, but took the single side. The DFT is 1024 block, 1000 data plus 24 for the padding. Having the Fs and  NFFT be multiples of each other seems to give a reasonably better blue plot around the fundamental frequency.

Comment: *"The DFT is 1024 block, 1000 data plus 24 for the padding."* and *"... hence the 20 cycles. It is the entire length DFT..."*  are inconsistent with each other.  your 20 cycles do **not** take up the entire DFT length.  if they did, there would be a **single** non-zero bin in the positive frequencies (bin 20) and a single bin in the negative frequencies (bin 1004, which is 1024-20) and **no** little skirting or sidelobes around that single spike.

Comment: What I mean by "*The DFT is 1024 block, 1000 data plus 24 for the padding.*" and "*It is the entire length DFT*" is that what you see in the bottom subplot **is** the entire DFT length of 1024 then taken single side. The "*...hence 20 cycles*" is for the 20 Hz signal for 1 second duration in the top subplot.

Comment: Well, then I would say to you that it is not necessarily the case that *"... the tapering of the signal by non-rectangular window explain from (1) the better localization of the maximum..."*  A rectangular window of 1024 points (which is really no window at all) with the sinusoid making exactly 20 cycles in that aperture, that will show the maximum more clearly and accurately than anything else.

Comment: Thank you @robertbristow-johnson for your input. It appears that, for an integer number of cycles as input to the FFT, it is indeed not the case when Fs and NFFT are multiples of each other.

Comment: As far as (1) goes, looking at the DFT as a projection of the signal onto a sum of complex sinusoids provides sufficient intuition for what would happen since sine is the difference of positive and negative complex sinusoids at 20 Hz and -20Hz. Thus, the only possible projection is onto the complex sinusoid at 20Hz. Is that where you're going with this?

Comment: For (2), perhaps thinking about multiplication of the windows in the time domain is equivalent to convolution in the frequency domain. The FFT of the rect is a sinc with first sidelobe 13 dB down, whereas the FFT of a Hann window has much lower sidelobes. Convolving these with the delta function (FFT of an infinite-length sinusoid) gives smaller side lobes by virtue of the properties of the FFTs of the windows. Not sure if this is what you're looking for since this seems to me to be part of theory of leakage.

Comment: @MrMas for question (1) I still don't see how, knowing that you have a 20 Hz sine, you can conclude that *"Thus, the only possible projection is onto the complex sinusoid at 20Hz"*. This **is** the question I asked, how. Yes, from linear combination in equation (1) I'm more thinking in that way, in terms of projections. For question (2), my *guess* is that it could be understood from the answer to question (1).

Comment: @Gilles The DFT is a projection of a signal onto a sum of harmonically related sinusoids. The the projection of a sinusoid onto any harmonically related sinusoid over the period of the lowest-frequency sinusoid is 0 *unless* the two sinusoids have the same frequency. (Try multiplying two sinusoids of different frequencies and then integrating over the period of the sinusoid). The nature of sinusoids is that they only project onto themselves and project no energy onto other sinusoids. If you think about it this way, it *may* help you develop intuition about what happens with the DFT.

Comment: @MrMas It's exactly in that direction I was heading, unless there is another way of looking at it. Thanks for the input ! If you have the answer with you, you can put it and I will accept it. Otherwise I'm going to read some more and see how to come up with explicit answers to the questions.